# Enhance Ability on multiple targets: same effect for everyone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[Enhance Ability](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/spells/enhanceAbility.htm) can be "upcasted" (cast using a higher spell slot) to target more creatures.

Does the caster choose which effect to apply for each target, or are the same effects applied to each target?